# DiscordJS & Heroku: Error: Cannot find module '../Modal'

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord.js

So this is lately one of the most popular issues in discord.js community. Appears after updating to d.js v13.7.0 and higher. While it works perfectly on a PC or etc., it fails to run on Heroku hosting with the following message:

```
Error: Cannot find module '../Modal'
```

This is clear that the issue is on Heroku's side, because `Modal` file can be found in discord.js dependency folder in `node_modules`.

I have NodeJS v18.3.0, have tried reinstalling discord.js with multiple methods, nothing helped.

I wasn't able to find any solutions to the problem, have anyone over here found the solution?

Answer (score -1):

Im pretty sure that you didn't create a file called `.gitignore` because it shows that your problem is on the folders `'../Modal'`, Before deploying it to heroku, you should `ignore` the `2 files` on your project.

1. node_modules
2. .env (if you have)

To remove these 2 on your deploying, create a file on your main folder named `.gitignore` and right down the following:

```
node_modules
.env
```

Comment: i have node_modules checked in .gitignore

Comment: its not on my side, its about compatibility, compatibility of discord.js v13.8.0 & heroku

Comment: if so, probably heroku can't find the package called `Modal` I've encountered this issue before. Some of the package can't find